# Find columns which are indexed in a given table

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I trying to find out the columns on which there is an index created for a given table. I am using below query to know the index name for a table:

```
select index_name from dba_indexes where table_name='TABLE_NAME';
```

Please help me how to get the columns on which the index is created.
How to know if the index is a unique or non-unique index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `all_ind_columns`:

More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1100.htm#i1577532